# BindableCollection changes when other ObservableCollection changes

Tags: wpf, observablecollection, caliburn.micro

Is there a way to update an ObservableCollection with the items which are added/deleted in other ObservableCollection?

How can I update my ViewModel's BindableCollection when items are added, removed in FullyObservableCollection?

It is important to note I am trying to use MVVM pattern with Caliburn.Micro.

**VieModel**

```
private BindableCollection<Employees> _employees = new BindableCollection(OracleConnector.GetEmployeeRepositorys());

public BindableCollection<Employees> Employees
    {
        get
        {

            return _employees;
        }
        set
        {
            OracleConnector.List.CollectionChanged += (sender, args) =>
            {
                _employees = OracleConnector.List;
            };
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Employees);

        }
    }
```

**OracleConnector**

```
public class OracleConnector
{
    public static FullyObservableCollection<Employees> List = new FullyObservableCollection<Employees>();

    public static FullyObservableCollection<Employees> GetEmployeeRepositorys()
    {

        using (IDbConnection cnn = GetDBConnection("localhost", 1521, "ORCL", "hr", "hr"))
        {
            var dyParam = new OracleDynamicParameters();

            try
            {

                var output = cnn.Query<Employees>(OracleDynamicParameters.sqlSelect, param: dyParam).AsList();
                foreach (Employees employees in output)
                {
                    List.Add(employees);
                }

            }
            catch (OracleException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Connection to database is not available.\n" + ex.Message, "Database not available", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }
            return List;

        }
    }

}
```

I am able to detect if changes are made in the FullyObservableCollection but I don't know how to pass them to the ViewModel.

Comment: use a getter/setter for your observable and update the other collection in your setter

Comment: The collection I am trying to update is in my ShellViewModel. I am using caliburn.micro as MVVM framework. ShellViewModel.Employees cannot be called outside view model and I don't know it is a good practice to update it like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `IEventAggregator` in the `OracleConnector` class when you add a new employee. Publish a `EmployeeAddedMessage` which contains the new employee. Make sure you publish on the correct thread too. You are likely to need to use `PublishOnUiThread` method. The `ShellViewModel` is then able to implement the `IHandle<EmployeeAddedMessage>` as a method probably called `Handle(EmployeeAddedMessage msg)`. Inside the `Handle` method you can then add the `Employee` to the appropriate `Employee` collection.

You may need to add the `OracleConnector` to your application bootstrapper as well as the `EventAggregator` class that Caliburn Micro provide. Your `ShellViewModel` will also need to call the `Subscribe(this)` method on the event aggregator. Both the `OracleConnector` and `ShellViewModel` need to be using the same instance of the event notifier. So make sure you register the event aggregator as a singleton.

See [here](https://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/event-aggregator) for more details about using the event notification. Also, my application [here](https://github.com/digitalbricklayer/workbench) uses event notification for application events.

Comment: This is a really good suggestion. Will it work if OracleConnector is a class library on a separate project than UI?

Comment: So long as the library has a reference to the Caliburn Micro library I don't see why not. If you are reluctant to add such a reference, then you could create and wire up some kind of event on the `OracleConnector` class that is listened to in the GUI project. Something like `OracleConnector.EmployeeAdded` or something like that.